# Try to use the google drive - failed in the authorisation

Tags: android, token, google-drive-api

After a few long days, where I looked at almost all solutions in this area I give up. I try to use the Googgle drive but already in teh simplest code it fails. the code:

```
static String accountName = "xxx@gmail.com"; //my personal google account for trial purposes
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.sync);

    syncbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.syncButton);
    syncbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           Context synccontext = getApplicationContext();

           GoogleAccountCredential credential;

             String scope = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata";

           //from some reason the eclipse mark the usingOAuth2 as deprecated, I failed to        figure out why
           credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(synccontext, scope);

           credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

             try {
              credential.getToken();
              } catch (IOException e2) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              System.out.println ("token IOException = " + e2);
              } catch (GoogleAuthException e2) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              System.out.println ("token GoogleAuthException = " + e2);
    }

             service = getDriveService(credential);
```

in the stage of the getToken there are the following error messages:

```
09-01 12:24:48.645: W/dalvikvm(1131): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1914 (auth_client_play_services_err_notification_msg) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
09-01 12:24:48.645: D/dalvikvm(1131): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x001a
09-01 12:24:48.645: I/dalvikvm(1131): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x077b at 0x42 in Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil;.a
09-01 12:24:48.645: I/dalvikvm(1131): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x077c at 0x54 in Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil;.a
09-01 12:24:48.650: I/dalvikvm(1131): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0778 at 0x73 in Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil;.a
09-01 12:24:48.650: I/dalvikvm(1131): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0779 at 0x76 in Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil;.a
09-01 12:24:48.650: I/dalvikvm(1131): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0777 at 0x79 in Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil;.a
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131): Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock and/or ANRs
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131): java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.b(Unknown Source)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:277)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at com.gal.shoppinglist.SyncActivity$1.onClick(SyncActivity.java:80)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
09-01 12:24:48.665: E/GoogleAuthUtil(1131):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 12:24:48.665: D/AndroidRuntime(1131): Shutting down VM
09-01 12:24:48.665: W/dalvikvm(1131): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4106f2a0)
09-01 12:24:48.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 12:24:48.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock
09-01 12:24:48.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.b(Unknown Source)
09-01 12:24:48.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
09-01 12:24:48.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
09-01 12:24:48.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:277)
09-01 12:24:48.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.gal.shoppinglist.SyncActivity$1.onClick(SyncActivity.java:80)
09-01 12:24:48.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
```

I guess it is something basic and I appologise in advance for it. I will highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

An authentication failure usually relates to two things:

1. API key mismatch, or
2. You have forgotten to enable the **Drive API** service in your **Google APIs Console** under **Services**

If it's number 2, enable the service, then **recreate** the key by pressing **Generate new key** under **API Access**

**EDIT:** The deprecation is related to the API you target. If Android has removed that command after certain API level and your Target API is higher, it shows that you are going to cause problems. You need to find the replacement command (if one exists) for the deprecated ones and call the specific command depending on the Device's API level.

Comment: I beleive I did both enables the DRIVE API and created a key. regard the key as it is in the debug mode it should not have matterred as far as I understood but I did it anyhow

Comment: Go onto your API Console, and check the Drive API service, are there any calls made to it? If there are 0 calls, the problem lies in your App.

Comment: There is 0 calls, and I agree the problem is in the app. The issue is that I failed to solve it and this is why I need help

Comment: I have not experimented with Google Drive API, however, if you haven't already, I recommend you starting Drive Tutorials and Examples by Android and learn/modify that example code: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Comment: I did quite extensively and tried their samples as is. hiowever the results are the same, so again it is for sure something in my domain I just fail to spot it.

Comment: Since when did the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method start throwing a GoogleAuthException with message "BadUsername" for an email that is not registered on a device, instead of the previous exception IllegalArgumentException with message "Non existing account 'email_address'" ?  
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context , java.lang.String, java.lang.String)